# Sum of infinite array fails one test case

Tags: c++

Problem Statement:

> Given an array “A” of N integers and you have also defined the new
> array “B” as a concatenation of array “A” for an infinite number of
> times. For example, if the given array “A” is [1,2,3] then, infinite
> array “B” is [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,.......]. Now you are given Q queries,
> each query consists of two integers “L“ and “R”. Your task is to find
> the sum of the subarray from index “L” to “R” (both inclusive) in the
> infinite array “B” for each query.

```
vector<int> sumInRanges(vector<int> &arr, int n, vector<vector<long long>> &queries, int q) {
    
    vector<int> ans;
    for(int i=0; i<q; i++){
        int l = queries[i][0];
        int r = queries[i][1];
        int sum = 0;
        for(int j=l-1; j<r; j++){
            sum += arr[j%n];
        }
        ans.push_back(sum);
    }
    return ans;
}
```

One test case is failing. Could someone suggest the edit required?

Comment: Which are the range of values (can overflow happen)?

Comment: "Your task is ..." so it's our task now! We are a team!

Comment: Why did you write `j = l - 1`?

Comment: @mkrieger1: conversion from 1-indexing to 0-indexing I would say.

Comment: @Jarod42 Or not. The problem statement says nothing about 0-indexing or 1-indexing. I would like to hear that from Neeraj.

Comment: BTW, wonder if you don't have TLE with some input.

Comment: What happens if you change `j = l - 1` to `j = l` and `j < r` to `j <= r`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 its because indexing is being done from 1 for the corresponding infinite array

Comment: What are the maximum values of `L` and `R`. `queries` vector is supposed to hold `long long`values ...

Comment: @Jarod42 here are the constraints :
1 <= T <= 100
1 <= N <= 10^4   
1 <= A[i] <= 10^9
1 <= Q <= 10^4
1 <= L <= R <= 10^18

Time Limit: 1sec

Comment: `int l = queries[i][0];` will obviously fail ...

Comment: You are missing the question's intention - think about why they said "array A is repeating infinitely in B" - if R-L was greater than length of A, then you can optimize the sum calculation, rather than summing all items from L to R.

Comment: It is a good practice to provide link to task you have problem with, so others could try it to and verified that you didn't misunderstood something or omitted vital information. Is [this a problem](https://www.codingninjas.com/codestudio/problems/sum-of-infinite-array_873335) you are trying to solve?

Comment: Considering the limits, you're probably failing because it takes too long (10^18 nanoseconds is almost 32 years). Hint: think about the relationship between the result, the sum of the repeated array "A", (R-L)/n, and (R-L)%n.

Comment: Thank your @MarekR Actually i am new here on this platform. As for the problem here is the link : https://www.codingninjas.com/codestudio/problems/sum-of-infinite-array_873335?leftPanelTab=0

Answer (score 0):

Good I've found link to your actual problem.

Take a look on note:

[Sum Of Infinite Array](https://www.codingninjas.com/codestudio/problems/sum-of-infinite-array_873335)

> ##### Note :
>
> ```
> The value of the sum can be very large, return the answer as modulus 10^9+7.
> ```
>
> ....
>
> ###### Constraints :
>
> ```
> 1 <= T <= 100
> 1 <= N <= 10^4   
> 1 <= A[i] <= 10^9
> 1 <= Q <= 10^4
> 1 <= L <= R <= 10^18
>
> Time Limit: 1sec
> ```

So basically your code have problem with integer overflow.

Your implementation is to simple. You have to leverage fact that this infinitive array has a period otherwise your code never meets time requirement. You do not have to calculate sum of the all indexes, you can skip a lot and calculate correction using multiplication (modulo).

Answer (score 0):

Your solution takes time proportional to `l - r` because it tries every number.

But this is unnecessary, as there are `n` identical periods that you can sum in a single go. So the running time can be made proportional to the length of `A` instead. (Find the multiple of the length just above or on `l` and the multiple just below `r`.)

E.g. to sum from `10` to `27` inclusive, use

```
1231231231|231231231231231231|23123123... = 1231231231|23+4x123+1|23123123...
```